# What is the name for `<(...)` 'operator' in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm familiar with creating 'temporary files' for command input in bash, e.g.

```
cat file_1 <(echo hello) file_2
```

I want to read more about the subject, but I don't know the name of the `<( )` operator.  I suspect it's a kind of IO redirect.

Is there a name for this notation/operator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

> Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or
> output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary
> file.

Also from [Bash Reference Manual → 3.5.6 Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

> Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename. It takes the form of
>
> ```
> <(list)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> >(list)
> ```
>
> The process list is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename. This filename is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion. If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list. Note that no space may appear between the < or > and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct would be interpreted as a redirection. Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.
>
> When available, process substitution is performed simultaneously with parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Also known as 'anonymous FIFO'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11898694)

Comment: @TobySpeight It actually does provide an answer to the question.