# multiple conditions on 'if'

Tags: bash, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to write a bash script that loops over directories that start with one of two strings in a given folder. I wrote the following:

```
for aSubj in /wherever/*
    if [ [ -d $aSubj ] && [ [ $aSubj == hu* ] || [ $aSubj == ny* ] ] ]; then
        .
        .
    fi
done
```

When I try and run this I get a syntax error on the line of the 'if': syntax error near unexpected token 'if'

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your use of `[` and `[[` seems a bit random.

Comment: each condition has just one '[', but some of them are nested

Comment: Why are you trying to nest them?

Comment: because it's (a) & (b or c), rather than (a & b) or c

Comment: Right, but `[` doesn't nest that way. `[` is actually a command, nearly equivalent to the `test` command, and it doesn't recognize a `[` in its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st line should be

```
for aSubj in /wherever/*; do
```

Comment: I have another question - the variable aSubj is ending up as the entire file path (that is, /wherever/aSubj ). How can I get the variable to be just the directory name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mention multiple conditions, just nest them with `( )`:

```
$ d=23
$ ( [ $d -ge 20 ] && [ $d -ge 5 ] ) || [ $d -ge 5 ] && echo "yes"
yes
```

However, in this case you may want to use a regular expression as described in [Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21112707):

```
[[ $aSubj =~ ^(hu|ny)* ]]
```

This checks if the content in the variable `$aSubj` starts with either `hu` or `ny`.

Or even use the regular expression to fetch the files. For example, the following will match all files in `ttt/` directory whose name starts by either `a` or `b`:

```
for file in ttt/[ab]*
```

---

Note you can also feed your loop with using a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854) with `find` containing a regular expression (samples in [How to use regex in file find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5249779/1983854)):

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
   # .... things
done < <(find your_dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/\(hu\|ny\).*')
```

For example, if I have the following dirs:

```
$ ls dirs/
aa23  aa24  ba24  bc23  ca24
```

I get this result if I look for directories whose name starts by either `ca` or `bc`:

```
$ find dirs -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*/\(ca\|bc\).*'
dirs/bc23
dirs/ca24
```