# how i can iterate on files as in for in java?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

i want to do following action

```
for(File : find - ".java"){
// here i will do grep on the file, i want to process each file separetely
}
```

What is way to do this in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854):

```
while IFS= read -r name;
do
    # do things with $name, which contains the name of the file
done < <(find -type f -name "*.java")
```