# find and then grep and then iterate through list of files

Tags: unix, grep, find, sh, aix

I have following script to replace text.

```
grep -l -r "originaltext" . |  
while read fname  
do  
sed 's/originaltext/replacementText/g' $fname > tmp.tmp  
mv tmp.tmp $fname  
done
```

Now in the first statement of this script , I want to do something like this.

```
find . -name '*.properties' -exec grep "originaltext" {} \;
```

How do I do that?
I work on AIX, So --include-file wouldn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I prefer to use `find` to FIND files rather than `grep`. It looks obvious : )

Using [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854) you can feed the `while` loop with the result of `find`:

```
while IFS= read -r fname  
do  
  sed 's/originaltext/replacementText/g' $fname > tmp.tmp  
  mv tmp.tmp $fname  
done < <(find . -name '*.properties' -exec grep -l "originaltext" {} \;)
```

Note I use `grep -l` (big `L`) so that `grep` just returns the name of the file matching the pattern.

Comment: Hey fedorqui, looks like that filer "*.properties" doesn't look to be working. If I echo fname in the loop, I don't see properties file

Comment: @Ahmad I did not really follow what is your purpose. Since you use `find ... -exec grep`, you may want to say `grep -l` (that is, lowercase `L`) so that it just provides the name of the file as output.

Answer (score 1):

You could go the other way round and give the list of '*.properties' files to grep.  For example

```
grep -l "originaltext" `find -name '*.properties'`
```

Oh, and if you're on a recent linux distribution, there is an option in grep to achieve that without having to create that long list of files as argument

```
grep -l "originaltext" --include='*.properties' -r .
```

Comment: first one not working and as I already mentioned second option is not available to me. Thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: Oops, didn't read the last line, sorry.  Well read fedorqui's answer.