# Is there a way to copy unstaged files in git to a different location?

Tags: git, shell

I want to "pluck" (if that's a good word for it) just the unstaged files and copy them to a different directory. I don't want any other files in the repo... just these unstaged files.

Is there a git command or shell + git command to do this?

---

**Updating question to respond to questions:**

- I want to keep the file structure and files
- I am open to any combo of git and shell wizardry

Comment: do you want to keep the folder structure, or just the files?

Comment: Are you interested in workarounds that involve `git status` piped to `grep`, or do you expect something more out-of-the-box?

Comment: I updated my question to respond to your comments/questions. Thanks guys.

Comment: If the files are text, you can view the files as such: `git show :<file>`. Not sure if this is gonna help in any way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git ls-files -m | tar Tc - | tar Cx /path/to/other/dir
```

and if windows wasn't a factor I'd do the tarpipe thing with just `cpio -pd /path/to/other`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: There does not seem to be an option in ls-files to show new (untracked) files, --others includes files in target...

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix=/xxx/
git status --porcelain | grep -e "^ M " | while read mark path
do
mkdir -p $prefix/$(dirname "$path")
cp -v "$path" $prefix/"$path"
done
```

`prefix` is the root folder of the backups.

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried creating the prefix dir first, but still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `-s` for `--short` you can get the list of files in a nice (porcelain) way:

```
$ git status -s
 M dir1/file1.py
 M dir2/file2.py
```

So then it is just a matter of looping through this list using [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854):

```
while IFS=" " read -r _ file; do
   echo "$file --"  # or whatever "mv" you want to do
done < <(git status -s)
```

This slurps the first column using the throw away variable `_` and the rest is stored in `$file`.