# split files greater than 500kb at particular directory

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to split  files which are >500kb. For this first I use find to list all such files `find .  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log'  -size +500k` that returns "./filename" and then I write another command to split file according to my requirement `split -b 500k -d -a 4 filename filename.` here filename is the output of first command. Now can someone help me to combine both of them such that the output of first is input of second command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a one liner?

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -name '*'  -size +500k -exec 'split' '-b' '500k' '-d' '-a' '4' '{}' '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31703275/1983854) for this:

```
while IFS= read file
do
   split -b 500k -d -a  4 "$file" "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.log' -size +500k)
```

That is: the `while` loop gets fed by the `find` output.